# Scala : URL rewriting (e.g. ../../someurl)

Tags: string, scala

I have two URLS of the type :

`val url = "../../a/b/c.html"`

`val parentURL = "http://www.someurl.com/section1/section2/section3.html"`

What I am looking to do is to produce a resulting String as follow :

`val resultingString = "http://www.someurl.com/section1/a/b/c.html"`

I can count the occurrences of ".." in the first URL, but I have no idea how to use it to kind of "substring" the parentURL the way I want.

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the standard functions of Scala as follows if you want to parse it yourself:

```
val parts = url.split('/').foldLeft(parentURL.split('/')) { case (cur, dir) =>
  if (dir == ".") cur // stay in current directory
  else if (dir == "..") cur.dropRight(1) // go up in the tree
  else cur :+ dir // cd into directory
}

parts.mkString("/") // build the string back
```

Answer (score 6):

Handling URLs is messy with all kinds of exceptions. I recommend using the methods provided by the JVM to handle this.

```
val parsed = new java.net.URL(parentURL)
new URL(
  parsed.getProtocol,
  parsed.getHost,
  parsed.getPort,
  java.nio.file.Paths.get(parsed.getFile, url).normalize.toString)
```